# Sorting arraylist in android not working

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, comparable, compareto

Im calling collections.sort on an array list of objects of class appointment but it wont sort nothing happens

This is how im calling the collections sort

```
 ArrayList<appointment> listoffappointments = new ArrayList<appointment>();

 //then everytime on button click user adds a new appointment after setting the following code is executed 
{
 Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();                
 calendar1.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, temphour, tempmin);
 appointment tempppt = new appointment(c2,tempstring1);
 listoffappointments.add(tempppt);
 Collections.sort(listoffappointments);
}
```

Here is the class can someone find the issue thanks

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class appointment  implements Comparable<appointment> {

Calendar time;
String Text;
public appointment(Calendar tempc, String temptext) {
    Text = temptext;
    time = tempc;
}

public void settext(String text)
{
    Text = text;
}
public String gettext()
{
    return Text;
}
public String toString() {
    return Text;
}
public Long gettimeofappt()
{
    return time.getTimeInMillis();

}

@Override
public int compareTo(appointment o) {
     return (this.gettimeofappt() < o.gettimeofappt() ) ? -1: (this.gettimeofappt() > o.gettimeofappt() ) ? 1:0 ;  

}


}
```

Comment: where is your collections.sort call?

Comment: in my other class that has the array list of objects of class appointment

Comment: You should include that code in your question.

Comment: added it in the question now @nKn

Comment: assume i already have elements of type appointment in my arraylist

Comment: in appoint class there is time,text so on which type you want to sort time or text?

Comment: @PankajAndroid i wish to compare by time.gettimeinmillis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are returning a Long object, Change your compareTo like:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(appointment o) {
     return this.gettimeofappt().compareTo(o.gettimeofappt() );

}
```

`Long.compareTo` compares two Long objects numerically, and Retunrs:

> the value 0 if this Long is equal to the argument Long; a value less
>   than 0 if this Long is numerically less than the argument Long; and a
>   value greater than 0 if this Long is numerically greater than the
>   argument Long (signed comparison).

Comment: even with  "return this.gettimeofappt().compareTo(o.gettimeofappt() );" nothing changes @blackbelt

Comment: can you print the content of the ArrayList ? Just for debugging puropse

Comment: contents of array list come out exactly in order they wen in so first then first second then first second third

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Look at [Sorting ArrayList (String ArrayList and custom class)](http://limbaniandroid.blogspot.in/2013/01/sorting-arraylist-string-arraylist-and.html)